# springboot failed to start, yet no exception log was print? why?

Tags: exception, spring-boot

SpringApplication.run(DemoApp.class, args) occured BeanCreationException, however it didn't print the log. Why? (I can make it run but why no logs)

Here is the exception I copied when debugging

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer#0' defined in class path resource [dao/spring-dao.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [dao/spring-dao.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.github.pagehelper.PageHelper#654c1a54' of type [com.github.pagehelper.PageHelper] while setting bean property 'plugins' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.github.pagehelper.PageHelper] for bean with name 'com.github.pagehelper.PageHelper#654c1a54' defined in class path resource [dao/spring-dao.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.pagehelper.PageHelper
```

Here is the source code position.

```
public ConfigurableApplicationContext run(String... args) {
    try{
       ......
    }catch (Throwable ex) {
        handleRunFailure(context, listeners, analyzers, ex);-------//stuck in here
        throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
    }
}


private void handleRunFailure(ConfigurableApplicationContext context,SpringApplicationRunListeners listeners, FailureAnalyzers analyzers,Throwable exception) {
    try {
        ......
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.warn("Unable to close ApplicationContext", ex);
    }
    ReflectionUtils.rethrowRuntimeException(exception);-------//stuck in here
}


public static void rethrowRuntimeException(Throwable ex) {
    if (ex instanceof RuntimeException) {
        throw (RuntimeException) ex; --------//stuck in here and then all stopped
    }
    if (ex instanceof Error) {
        throw (Error) ex;
    }
    throw new UndeclaredThrowableException(ex);
}
```

Comment: Well the logs says: `nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.pagehelper.PageHelper`, what would you generally do when class not found on cp?

Comment: when i try-catch "SpringApplication.run(DemoApp.class, args)" and e.printStackTrace() , then it can print the log. Why this method (run) designed this way ----- it can throw exception, and needn't try-catch？？

Comment: @SagarRohankar if it throw exception which I must try-catch , i will not have to debug to see what's wrong! Why designed this way?

Comment: Why are you catching the startup exceptions? Jsut let them be thrown and it will be logged... the exception is right there in front of you. Your runtime class path doesn't have a required class.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe  it is throwed,but never logged, i can't see the stacktrace unless i try-catch

Comment: @SagarRohankar  I hava stated that I can solved the problem, you see? but why it never logged    @ DarrenForsythe

Comment: Are you running `1.5.7`? If so look at [#10470](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/10470) and try to upgrade to `1.5.8`.

Comment: @StephaneNicoll  I just tried 1.5.8 in my case, it didn't work, unless i try-catch it and e.printStackTrace manually

Comment: @counterFish Can you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](/help/mcve)?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I start a new project,it worked fine. My project integraded with dubbo rpc framework ,it happened this. Do you still need a demo??

Answer (score -2):

My project integraded with a rpc framework-dubbo, and it happened this. I start a new project ,it works fine.